# Vue2: how to register a component from a compiled single file component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue2 and Single-File Components.

I have some complex components that I have compiled via Rollup

e.g.

#### /src/components/a.vue

```
<template>
  ....
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    ...
  }
</script>
```

#### /src/components/b.vue

```
<template>
  ...
  <ComponentA/>
  ....
</template>

<script>
  import ComponentA from './a'
  export default {
    ...
    components: {
      ...,
      ComponentA,
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
</script>
```

#### /src/index.js

```js
import ComponentA from './components/a'
import ComponentB from './components/b'

var myMod = {}
myMod.ComponentA = ComponentA;
myMod.ComponentB = ComponentB;

window.myMod = my.Mod
```

which together ends up in **build/main.js** and I source into my project.

My project is not a full view app.

If I want to use either ComponentA or ComponentB in my app, do I always need to do:

```
var foo = 10;
var compBInstance = new Vue({
     el: '#this-comp-b-instance',
     components: {myMod.ComponentB},
     data: function() {
       // data defined outside of this
       foo: foo
     },
     template: `<ComponentB :foo='foo'/>`
})
```

or is there a way for me to be able to just write `<ComponentB :foo='10'/>`

Comment: You could compile the components you want to use using vue-cli 3 to web-components (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component) and include those directly - if that's an option for you.

Comment: uses [Vue Guide: Vue.component](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component), then register your components like `Vue.component(myMod.ComponentB)`, then you can direct-use it in your app.